# Using Apache Camel JPA producer with hibernate and plain Java DSL

Tags: hibernate, jpa, apache-camel

I am new to Camel and have been trying it out for polling a directory for XML files and writing to a database, using Hibernate. In order to understand how everything links together I want to wire everything up using straight Java DSL before I move it to Spring xml config. I got it to work exactly as expected using beans and my own methods:

```
class MyRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("file://test")
        .bean(parser, "parseXml")
        .bean(parser, "store");
    }
}
```

Now I want to try out the built-in JPA producer, so I changed it to:

```
    class MyRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("file://test")
        .bean(parser, "parseXml")
        .to("jpa:soccerfeed?persistenceUnit=sportsstats");
    }
}
```

But I get the error:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: 'hibernate.dialect' must be set when no Connection available

I have tried to link up my CamelContext with my persistence.properties file which specifies my hibernate.dialect (works fine for my bean):

```
    public void setUp() throws Exception {

    final Properties persistenceProperties = new Properties();
    InputStream is = null;
    try {
        is = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("persistence.properties");
        persistenceProperties.load(is);
    } finally {
        if (is != null) {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException ignored) {

            }
        }
    }

    entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("sportsstats", persistenceProperties);
    context = JAXBContext.newInstance("sportsstats");
}

    private void run() throws Exception {

            camelContext = new DefaultCamelContext();

            JpaComponent jpa = new JpaComponent();
    jpa.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
    jpa.setCamelContext(camelContext);
    Endpoint jpaEndpoint = jpa.createEndpoint("jpa:soccerfeed");

    camelContext.addEndpoint("jpa:soccerfeed", jpaEndpoint);

            // Add some configuration by hand ...
            camelContext.addRoutes(new MyRouteBuilder());

            // Now everything is set up - lets start the context
            camelContext.start();

            // keep alive
            while(true) {
                Thread.sleep(10000);
            }
}
```

How do I get my JPA endpoint in Camel to pick up my settings in persistence.properties?

EDIT: It seems the alternative would be to move the properties from my properties file into my persistence.xml file as  elements. However, I would like to avoid doing this if possible as it will make maintenance of dev/prod releases harder. Is there a way to link persistence.xml to a properties file? (eg < properties file="persistence.properties" /> or something?)

Comment: Are you able to run this code?